# Return 404 instead of 403 when @PostAuthorize fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Let's say I have the following controller. (Assume that `Order.customer` is the customer the order belongs to and only they should be able to access it.)

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {
    @GetMapping
    @PostAuthorize("returnObject.customer == authentication.principal")
    public Order getOrderById(long id) {
        /* Look up the order and return it */
    }
}
```

After looking up the order, `@PostAuthorize` is used to make sure it belongs to the authenticated customer. If it is not, Spring responds with a 403 Forbidden.

Such an implementation has a problem: Clients can distinguish between orders that do not exist and orders they have no access to. Ideally, 404 should be returned in both cases.

While this could be solved by injecting the `Authentication` into the handler method and implementing custom logic there, is there any way to achieve this using `@PostAuthorize` or a similar, declarative API?

Answer (score 2):

You could try a ControllerAdvice to catch and transform the AccessDeniedException, which PostAuthorize throws.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public String handleAccessDenied(AccessDeniedException e) {
        return "nothing here"; // or a proper object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a custom `AccessDeniedHandler` in your Spring Security configuration.
In the following example, the handler will return a 404 Not Found on an access denied failure.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // ...
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling
                        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                );
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }
}
```

```java
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getReasonPhrase());
    }
}
```